# Moving Timer from a View to a ViewModeller-class?

Tags: timer, swiftui

I have a Timer in my View right now, but I want to move it outside to my ViewModel-class. I have experimented a bit and came up with a working solution.

The code works and produces expected output, however I'm not sure if I have done everything in a proper way, so I would like some input on my code. Would you do it in another way? Is it better to have the Timer in the view and call viewModel.fetchData() in a .onRecieve()-modifier?

I still haven't decided on the layout of my final app. It will either be a TabView or a NavigationView and I want the timer to fetch data no matter in which subview I'm in at the moment. Maybe putting the timer and fetch-function in the view model is completely wrong (should it be in the model?). I'm feeling a bit lost with the MVVM-pattern. I'm also not very familiar with the Combine-framework, as you may see in the code.

The purpose of the code is to fetch data every n minute (in my code I check every second to speed things up for testing). If data is available I want to add it to a @Published property (simulating this by adding data every 5:th second).

This is my view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(vm.items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import Combine

@MainActor final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [String] = []
    
    private let timer: Publishers.Autoconnect<Timer.TimerPublisher>?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        timer = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1, runLoop: .main, mode: .default).autoconnect()
        self.startTimer()
    }
    
    private func fetchData(_ timerInterval: TimeInterval) async throws {
        print("timer fired")
        
        let ts = UInt32(timerInterval)
        if ts % 5 == 0 {
            print("New data available")
            items.append("Item \(ts)")
        }
    }
        
    private func startTimer() {
        cancellable = timer?.sink { [weak self] t in
            Task {
                try! await self?.fetchData(t.timeIntervalSince1970)
            }
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the broader question of whether the timer should be pulled out of the view, itself, I would tend to agree.

It begs the question, though, whether it really belongs in a view model, either. If this “try every five minutes” really is tied to this view, then fine, the view model is a reasonable choice. But, I wonder if it might better located to some broader network/api service object, not the view model. It depends upon whether this “try every five minutes” logic is really unique to this view and should only be performed while this view is presented, or whether it is something that the app might be trying whether this particular view was presented or not.

---

Setting that aside, a couple of tactical observations in your code snippet:

1. You do not need to save the timer publisher, itself. You only need the `cancellable` produced by `sink`.
2. You do not need to `cancel` on `deinit`. When the `cancellable` falls out of scope, it cancels the publisher for you.
3. You never want to use `try!` unless you know, for a fact, that it can never fail; i.e., you never want your app crash just because a network request fails.
4. As a stylistic matter, I really like putting private implementation methods in a separate extension. It affords better code folding, a more easily understood Xcode jump bar, and logical segregation of methods.
5. This is largely a matter of opinion, but I would do not start asynchronous tasks in the `init` of the view model, but rather have the view launch it (say, in its `.task` view modifier).
6. I would also advise either sticking with Combine (e.g., use `TimerPublisher`, but then use `URLSession` `dataTaskPublisher`) or adopt Swift concurrency (e.g., use [`AsyncTimerSequence`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Timer.md) and then the `async` `URLSession` method `data(from:delegate:)` or `data(for:delegate:)`)

   E.g., a Swift concurrency rendition might look like:

   ```swift
   import Foundation
   import AsyncAlgorithms

   @MainActor final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
       @Published private(set) var products: [Product] = []
       @Published private(set) var error: Error?

       func startTimer() async {
           for await _ in AsyncTimerSequence(interval: .seconds(5), clock: .continuous) {
               do {
                   products = try await productsFromNetwork()
               } catch {
                   self.error = error
               }
           }
       }
   }

   // MARK: - Private implementation

   extension ViewModel {
       func productsFromNetwork() async throws -> [Product] {
           let url = URL(string: "https://dummyjson.com/products")!
           let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
           let payload = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProductsResponse.self, from: data)
           return payload.products
       }
   }
   ```

   Technically, one can mix and match Combine and Swift concurrency, but it feels a bit muddled. I might advise picking one tech stack or the other. (I personally gravitate to Swift concurrency, nowadays.)

---

Not that it is terribly relevant, but this is the model I used for that `dummyjson.org` endpoint:

```swift
// MARK: - ProductsResponse

struct ProductsResponse: Decodable {
    let products: [Product]
    let total, skip, limit: Int
}

// MARK: - Product

struct Product: Decodable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let title, description: String
    let price: Int
    let discountPercentage, rating: Double
    let stock: Int
    let brand, category: String
    let thumbnail: String
    let images: [String]
}
```

And this was the `View`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let error = viewModel.error {
                Text(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            List(viewModel.products) { product in
                Text(product.description)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            await viewModel.startTimer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!